# What exchanges support Tenebrix?

Tags: tenebrix

Where can one exchange [Tenebrix](http://www.tenebrix.org/about--faq.html) (a CPU-friendly cryptocurrency) for Bitcoin?

Comment: Any chance you could link to a source on Tenebriz so that people will know more about what you're talking about?  It's not terribly well-known.

Comment: Is this StackExchange going to get polluted with each alternate currency to arrive?  Yes, I know the OP is asking about exchanging for bitcoin, but if I were to ask if there is anywhere that I can trade my baseball cards for bitcoin the question would get closed ... am I right?

Comment: @Stephen - I believe alternative currencies are on topic.

Comment: @ripper234 - I believe alternative currencies are off-topic advertisements.

Comment: @eldentyrell - http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-questions-about-other-crypto-currencies-on-topic

Comment: I think that it's important to keep the exchange of ideas fresh, and alternate blockchains are an important part of that. Some will be cheesier than others, but many are valid and important explorations and experimentations of theory. My vote? If the post looks like spam, then treat it like spam. But otherwise, all the alternate chains their place here. The Stack Exchange site should be a "Big Tent", IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BTC-E.com](https://btc-e.com/) currently supports trading pairs of BTC/USD, GG/BTC, SC/BTC, SC/USD and TBX/BTC. At the moment I believe it is the only exchange currently supporting Tenebrix.

Comment: BTC-E has since removed support for TBX: https://btc-e.com/news/58